# Visual Studio 2015 C++ Icon problems

Tags: c++, visual-studio, icons

I'm programming in C++, in Visual Studio IDE. When I try to make icon for my program I have problems. I can only edit 8 bit icons, and when I try 32 bit icon to edit, it disables editing tools.

This works
[image: Here works]

But this doesn't
[image: But here don't].

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the editor doesn't support this.

[This Microsoft help page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1dadd79.aspx) says

> **Note**
>   Using the Image Editor, you can view 32-bit images, but you cannot edit them.

Comment: How then I can add icons to my program?

Comment: Yes, that's a problem. Seems like the options are to use 24-bit images, or find an external icon editor.

Comment: I'm tried with external icon editor-Paint, and named file with .ico. But then shows "Cannot load external resource file". P.S. I can't find option in VS 2015 Image editor to edit 24-bit image.

Comment: @ĐorđeMilanović: You can't just rename a BMP file to `.ico` and expect to get an icon file. You need an actual icon editor.

Comment: Can I use Junior Icon Editor, i don't know any free software for icons except that.

Comment: Now is fine, I find solution. Problem was in resolutions. I used wrong.